# Scala handle null for int

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I have below code

```
   val num = (json \ "somenum").asOpt[String] => no restriction here can take as opt[int] also but need to handle null


var numNew: Int = null
    if (num.isEmpty || num < 100) {
      numNew = new Random().nextInt(SomeValue)
    }
    else {
      numNew = Integer.parseInt(num.toString)
    }
```

I want to implement it case/pattern matching code.I did try but less than `<` is not working

```
val output=  num match {
      case None =>  new Random().nextInt(100)
      case Some(x) => Integer.parseInt(num.toString)
      case Some(x)< 0 => new Random().nextInt(100) ==> throws error < not found
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean does not work?  Is it not compiling?  The ordering of cases is important.  There is a precedence order.  E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/7097107/259889

Comment: @jwvh how should I write it..can u help here?

Comment: operator `<` for `Option[A]` is undefined. You can fix it so: `case Some(x) if x < 0 => new Random().nextInt(100)` but only for types which have operator `<`. `Int` has it.

Comment: 1) you should not compare String with Int and 2) you should change order of cases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `num` is an `Option[String]`, as you've posted, then it looks like you have 4 different conditions to account for:

1. `num` is `None`
2. `num` is `Some(s)` but `s` is not a number
3. `num` is `Some(s)` where `s` is a number >= 100
4. `num` is `Some(s)` where `s` is a number < 100

It kind of depends on how you want to handle each of these, but I'd be tempted to start with a `fold()` and go from there.

```
val num :Option[String] = . . .

val isNum = "(\\d+)".r
num.fold("empty"){
  case isNum(digits) =>
    val n = digits.toInt
    if (n < 100) "less than 100"
    else "too big"
  case _ => "not digits"
}
```

testing:

```
val num :Option[String] = None         //"empty"
val num :Option[String] = Some("9X9")  //"not digits"
val num :Option[String] = Some("919")  //"too big"
val num :Option[String] = Some("99")   //"less than 100"
```

The `isNum` regex can be modified to account for negative and/or fractional numbers.

---

If there is no distinction between `num` is `None` and `num` is `Some(notNumber)` (that is you don't care about the difference) then things can be somewhat simplified.

```
num.flatMap(s => util.Try(s.toInt).toOption) match {
  case Some(n) if n < 100 => s"$n is less than 100"
  case Some(n)            => s"$n is too big"
  case _                  => "not a number"
}
```

Comment: if input is less than 0 or empty I want to create new random number else whatever is input should get assigned

Answer (score 1):

if num is option `Int`, you can write so:

```
val num: Option[Int] = (json \ "somenum").asOpt[Int]
var numNew: Int = num.filter(x => x < 0).getOrElse(new Random().nextInt(100))
```

in these code if num is `None` or `Some` with int less than zero, it will use random Int.

Read more about `Option` [scala documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html)